# How to get file names from command-line parameters in Python

Tags: python, input, output

I've got the following code:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as test, open("table.txt", "w") as table:
    reader = csv.reader(test, delimiter="\t")
    writer = csv.writer(table, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        if all(field not in keywords for field in row):
            writer.writerow(row)
```

How am I able to convert it to a .py file which let you define table.txt and test when you run it. So that one have to write:

```
Script.py test.txt output.txt
```

Comment: Check out [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html)

Comment: and [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

Comment: Because my question is not about the `with` but about being able to define these parameters. But I have changed it now :)

Comment: @PM2Ring: Well, you've got a couple extra upvotes on Meta now. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring: I don't know her, but her profile says "LAMP". As Yoda said, "Appealing can the Dark Side be, great clarity and simplicity it has, but illusion that is." Sounds more like Ruby to me than Perl. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

```
import sys
import csv

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as test, open(sys.argv[2], "w") as table:
      # more here
```

Note, `sys.argv[0]` contains the script name (in your case, `Script.py`). To get the first argument, you should get `sys.argv[1]`; to get the second argument, you should get `sys.argv[2]` and so on.

Comment: I have changed it now and included input and output within the `with` :)